# setState not defined | Not required to be defined?

Tags: flutter

I  have a check box that I would like users to check that they agree to receive email promotions.

I have followed numerous resources online and can get the checkbox to render, however it does not allow for the checkbox to be selected.

This is how I am building the checkbox:

```
Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                        child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                          // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),

                          Checkbox(
                            value: receive,
                            activeColor: Color(0xff33333D),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                value = receive;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          Text("I agree to receive emails",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ))
                        ])),
```

The error I am receiving is that `setState isn't defined for the type SignUp`

Has anyone ever received this error before? How can I rectify? Based upon my knowledge, SetState is not something that is required to be defined.

The full reproductive code sample is below:

```
class myApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Login',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'fonts/Avenir-Bold',
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: SignUp(),
    );
  }
}



    class SignUp extends StatelessWidget{ 
      @override
      bool receive = false;
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/SignUp_Photo.jpg",
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Sign Up',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 35,
                            fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                          child: Row(
                            // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  decoration:
                                      InputDecoration(hintText: "First Name"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                          child: Row(
                            // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  decoration:
                                      InputDecoration(hintText: "Email Address"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                          child: Row(
                            // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                            child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                              // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
    
                              Checkbox(
                                value: receive,
                                activeColor: Color(0xff33333D),
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    value = receive;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              Text("I agree to receive emails",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                  ))
                            ])),
                        const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            OutlineButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text('Login'),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xff33333D),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `setState`, use `StatefullWidget`. Those are the widgets that have mutable states.

Convert your StatelessWidget to StatefullWidget like this:

```
class SignUp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  @override
  bool receive = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              "assets/SignUp_Photo.jpg",
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Sign Up',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 35,
                        fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration:
                              InputDecoration(hintText: "First Name"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration:
                              InputDecoration(hintText: "Email Address"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                        child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                          // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),

                          Checkbox(
                            value: receive,
                            activeColor: Color(0xff33333D),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                receive = value; // value = receive; is wrong
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          Text("I agree to receive emails",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ))
                        ])),
                    const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        OutlineButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Login'),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xff33333D),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Replacing StatelessWidget with StatefulWidget did not recitfy... or is it a much larger fix?

Comment: @KirtM9 I have updated the answer. Try it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) on [stateless widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html), that is why you got such error.

> (Stateless Widget is) A widget that does not require mutable state.

You have to use a stateful widget, I advise that you read the documentation and try examples from the official site.

Comment: How would I make this a non-stateless widget then?

Comment: @KirtM9 use Statefull widget

Comment: @ToraCode Replacing StatelessWidget with StatefulWidget did not recitfy... or is it a much larger fix?

Comment: you dont want to setstate in a stateless widget, but on a variable that is located in a stateful widget, and will rebuild the widget according to the change

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `setState`, use `StatefullWidget`.

And your code is wrong on `setState` function.

Change

```
setState(() {
  value = receive;
});
```

To

```
setState(() {
  receive = value;
});
```